# How to make sure user input is a valid string in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am very new to JS,
how do I make sure that the user input is a valid string?
If the string is inside of the array, the game should continue. 
if the string is outside of the array, the game should ask user to input their guess again.

```
var color = ["AliceBlue","Black","FireBrick","GreenYellow","LightBlue","Ivory","MediumBlue","Indigo","SpringGreen","Moccasin"];

var target;
var guess_input_text;
var guess_input;
var finished = false;
var guesses = 0;
var rightAnswer;
var i = 0;

function do_game() {
    var random_number = Math.random()* color.length;
    var random_number_interger = Math.floor(random_number);
    target = random_number_interger + 1;
    rightAnswer = color[target];


    while(!finished) {
        guess_input_text = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors:\n\n" + color.sort()+ "\n\n The right answer is\n" + rightAnswer);
        guess_input = guess_input_text;
        guesses +=1;
       finished = check_guess();

    }
}


function check_guess() {



     if(guess_input < rightAnswer){

          console.log("Hint: your color is alphabetically lower than mine")
          return false;
      }
      else if( guess_input > rightAnswer) {

         console.log("Hint: your color is alphabetically higher than mine ")
          return false;
      }
     else (guess_input == rightAnswer)
      {
          console.log("Congrats!!!")
          return true;

      }  

    )
}
```

Comment: Use a select element instead (dropdown element) so you don't have to worry about case, spacing and spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use indexOf to check the position of guess_input in the color array.  It will return -1 if it is not present.

So:

```
function check_guess() {
    if (color.indexOf(guess_input) < 0) {
        console.log("Not a valid colour, try again.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: But the problem with this is you might enter a wrong string with a right first letter of the string. indexOf will not check if string is fully equal to one of the string inside of array

Comment: Yes it will, see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

Comment: That's no problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.prototype.find function with ES6 arrow functions to make it even snappier.

```
if(color.findIndex(e => e === guess_input) === -1){
    alert("Please guess again!);
}
```

The above code alerts the user to guess again if the `guess_input` isn't found in the array.